# What does this mean from a security perspective: "Caution: This repository is private but the published site will be public."

Tags: git, github

I've got a repo that will contain sensitive information, so in GitHub I made it private.  After doing so, however, this message is now displayed:

```
Caution: This repository is private but the published site will be public.
```

Can someone help me to understand what this message means?  Also, since I need to keep these sensitive files secure, what security considerations should be made?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It means that information stored in `gh-pages` branch of your repository will be publicly available via GitHub pages via `http://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`.

`gh-pages` branch is special branch, which content is automatically published by mechanism called [Github Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/).

Here is an example. I've created private repo [private_with_pages](https://github.com/teksisto/private_with_pages). You can not see it because, well, it's private. Nevertheless, file `index.html`, stored in branch `gh-pages`, is [publicly available](https://teksisto.github.io/private_with_pages/).

Now in settings of the github repository I see message “Caution: This repository is private but the published site will be public.”

According to this [help page](https://help.github.com/articles/unpublishing-a-project-pages-site/) the only way to disable this feature is remove `gh-pages` branch from github. How to remove remote branch is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely).

See related question: [Private pages for a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748082/private-pages-for-a-private-github-repo)

Comment: What exactly is the gh-pages brancch?  I've done some searching and can't locate a solid answer.  Also, what data is available in this public gh-pages branch?  I need all of the content pushed to this repo to stay private and secure.  Thanks.

Comment: First, check out `http://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`.  If there is some information you want to keep private, delete remote `gh-pages` branch .