# How are pages from a private repository accessed on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-pages

Is the project page (gh-pages branch) of a private repository visible from one's profile, or can it only be found if someone happens to guess the correct link to it?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10748082/3991344 (however, not a duplicate, as you're asking if it's publicly listed/discoverable, while that question just asks what happens with it in general)

Comment: Jan. 2021: GitHub pages for a private repo can be private... but only for GHE (GitHub Enterprise): see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65835521/6309

Answer (score 1):

According to [github help documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/):

> "GitHub Pages sites are publicly available on the internet, even if
>   their repositories are private. If you have sensitive data in your
>   Page repository, you may want to remove it before publishing."

If your github-pages sites is a [User Page it can only be published from `master`](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).  Otherwise you [set the publishing branch in the repo settings](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages) and you can select `master` or `gh-pages` to publish from if each exist.  (For pages that are not User or Org pages, there is also an option to [publish from a `/docs/` directory](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#publishing-your-github-pages-site-from-a-docs-folder-on-your-master-branch) on your `master` branch.)

The url to access the github pages site is `username.github.io` for User Pages or `username.github.io/projectname` for Project Pages as [summarized in this table.](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)

Comment: I have for a while been aware that GitHub Pages are publicly available. It was from this knowledge that my question sprung: how are these publicly available GitHub Pages accessed when the project repository is private? As I asked, are there links to them on one's profile somewhere (I couldn't find when I looked), or can they only be accessed if someone happens to guess their address?

Comment: i have amended the answer.  The link to the github-pages site (once published) is by convention.