# Switching from Private to Public repository but github pages does not publish site

Tags: html, css, node.js, github, github-pages

I created a personal website and pushed to the code to GitHub then published it on GitHub pages and everything was working well.

I then switched the repo from public to private and as expected, the published GitHub pages site was not accessible.

Now I again switched the repo from private to public but now (>30 minutes since going public), I get a 404 whenever when attempting to access the site.

repository: https://github.com/wandesky/portfolio
site: https://wandesky.github.io/portfolio/

I have tried giving the GitHub pages some time (>30 minutes) to see if the site will be back.
I have also tried to launch GitHub pages from the command prompt (as I did when initially launching the site) but still, the site does not go live.

```
  "name": "wandesky_portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Responsive portfolio website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "homepage": "https//wandesky.github.io/portfolio",
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css --recursive",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "author": "wandesky",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0"
  }
}
```

I expect that switching the repo back to public will make the site accessible.

Comment: I guess, Github does not allow private repos to publish. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748082/private-pages-for-a-private-github-repo)

Comment: Maybe main should point to `index.html` instead of `index.js`. I also see `dist/js/main.js` but no `index.js`

Comment: @nitin9nair the repository is currently public. What happened is that I switched to private then toggled back to public.

Comment: @BenHulan I tried changing index.js to index.html but still getting a 404. Also note that I used the same script the first time I published the website and it successfully published. Problems started when I toggled the repository from public to private then back to public.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working again. Fwiw, I don't think line 5 of your package.json is doing anything.

Comment: @BenHulan It really isn't doing anything. I removed it from the code in github

Answer (score 0):

When toggling a repo from public to private then back to public, it takes longer for the github pages to go live (again).

I went to bed and on waking up the next day, the site was up again.