# Password protect Bookdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, publish, bookdown

I want to use [R Bookdown](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown) to create a technical description document that should be shared with other people. However is should not be visible for everyone.

Is there an easy way to publish an Bookdown document online having it password protected?

Comment: How about using a private GitHub repository? You can [invite up to three collaborators](https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository). A cursory look suggests that alternatives such as GitLab, BitBucket offer similar setups.

Comment: we are using a private GitHub repository. I was thinking about Github Pages (https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-is-github-pages), but it seems that the hosted pages are always available for the whole public

Comment: It seems I misunderstood. I thought you asked about sharing the *source* code privately amongst collaborators. From what I know all GitHub Pages are public (even if they're created from private repos). A [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748082/private-pages-for-a-private-github-repo) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 6):

There are many possibilities. To name a few:

- If you publish your book to bookdown.org, [there is an option](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/135#issuecomment-230187149) that allows you to make your book private and share it with specific collaborators (this is free).
- You can publish to netlify.com and [password protect your site](https://www.netlify.com/docs/visitor-access-control/) (this is not a free feature).
- You can host your book on your own server, and configure your server software (e.g. Apache/Ngnix/...) to password protect the book.

Comment: I'm trying to use bookdown to make a personal [Commonplace book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonplace_book), pulling out and annotating quotes from books I've read. Ideally, I'd like it to be rendered somewhere, somehow online (so I can review it easily from multiple devices), but password protected and inaccessible (since obviously I'll have copyright material in there! - I don't want it indexed by google!). Is the bookdown.org option viable for this? Or what would you recommend, Yihui?