# How do I make a github website/webpage private?

Tags: github, github-pages, blogger

I currently have a blog set-up through Github using Jekyll. At first, it started out to be a public blog, but recently it has become more private for  me(i.e., blogging for therapeutic's sake and mental health). I wanted to make this blog site private.

I understand that you can make a repository private, but I want to continue using my published blog's website interface which is currently public. Is there a way around this? If not, what alternative options are there? (I tried using Blogger, and though I like its privacy settings, the published website interface is pretty weak.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Private pages for a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748082/private-pages-for-a-private-github-repo)

Answer (score 0):

You can have password protected pages on CloudCannon. You can also add a htaccess file on your custom hosting environment.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the encryption route. [Here](https://github.com/robinmoisson/staticrypt), the name staticrypt really says everything (I have a demo [here](https://yk-liu.github.io/secret)). It allows you to create a password for each page for your website. It used AES-256 encryption, so as far as I am concerned, a long password should suffice. You will be the only one to view the webpage. You can also have js on the webpage etc., so I believe you can maintain whatever you have on your website, (the address, format, etc.) while restricting access.

In the readme.md of `staticrypt`:

> Disclaimer if you have extra sensitive banking data you should
>   probably use something else!
>
> StatiCrypt generates a static, password protected page that can be
>   decrypted in-browser: just send or upload the generated page to a
>   place serving static content (github pages, for example) and you're
>   done: the javascript will prompt users for password, decrypt the page
>   and load your HTML.
>
> It basically encrypts your page and puts everything with a
>   user-friendly way to use a password in the new file.
>
> AES-256 is state of the art but brute-force/dictionary attacks would
>   be trivial to do at a really fast pace: use a long, unusual
>   passphrase.

To do that, first, generate your webpage as an HTML file and use [this link](https://robinmoisson.github.io/staticrypt/) (or locally) to encrypt your HTML file. Download the HTML file and upload it to your server.

I don't think GitHub allows you to make a "private" Github-pages.

Comment: What is "the encryption route"? How does it work together with Jekyll?

Comment: updated the answer. It does not work with Jekyll directly. You have to generate the HTML file from markdown first, but that could be done locally. The `staticrypt` takes over from there.