# Private repository github pages

Tags: github-pages

It's possible to use gh-pages on private repositories for a pro account?
I have Pro account and I created a private repository, but I want to use gh-pages for this private repository, I tried but it's not working, the only way is I need to change this private repo to the public?

Thanks

Comment: Jan. 2021: GitHub pages for a private repo can be private... but only for GHE (GitHub Enterprise): see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65835521/6309